# file inputs not aligning with rest of inputs

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

In my horizontal form, all of my input elements are aligning properly except for the file inputs.

They take 100% width and are floated to the left.

In my simple_form_bootstrap.rb my wrapper seems to configured properly with the label taking 3 and input taking 9.. but somehow in the generated html, it's not taken into account.

Wrapper:

```
config.wrappers :horizontal_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label, class: 'col-sm-3 control-label'

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

Form header:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', role: "form", multipart: true },
        wrapper: :horizontal_form,
        wrapper_mappings: {
          check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
          radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
          file: :horizontal_file_input,
          boolean: :horizontal_boolean
        }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
```

Form inputs in my form

```
 <%= f.fields_for :assets do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.input :attachment, as: :file, :label => "Image:" %>
  <% end %>
```

Generated html

```
<div class="form-group file optional post_assets_attachment">
<label class="file optional control-label" for="post_assets_attributes_0_attachment">
Image:</label>
<input class="file optional form-control" id="post_assets_attributes_0_attachment" name="post[assets_attributes][0][attachment]" type="file">
</div>
```

How come the simple_form settings don't apply to the file inputs?

Comment: file inputs do not style.. the browser styles it. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms check the file input

Comment: yes but i'm trying to style the wrapper not the input the itself. For the other controls such as text fields, simple_form automatically added col-sm-x for the label and col sm-x for the actual field. This doesn't get applied to input wrappers. It just adds form-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in the simple-form  3.1.0.rc1 sample application.

Looks like specifying the wrapper in the form header didn't work for some reason. Had to apply it directly to the input.

I changed:

```
<%= builder.input :attachment, as: :file, :label => "Image:" %>
```

to

```
<%= builder.input :attachment, as: :file, :label => "Image:", wrapper: :horizontal_file_input  %>
```

And it works perfectly now.